# error in xml file

Tags: android

i am preparing my android apps in which i want to create two row .it showing this error on the second tableRow.but i couldn't understand,how to resolve that error. 
the error is "The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed."it is coming on the second table row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableRow
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1">

    <!-- Screen Design for the SONGS -->
<ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/viewFlipper1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
  </ViewFlipper>

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

</TableRow>
```

Comment: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed. it is coming on the second row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that is the entire XML file it's missing a "root" element and is therefore not well-formed XML

Comment: you have to wrap both <TableRow> flags in some outer containing wrapper. the top level can only have one element

Comment: I assume the XML is being constructed as configuration information of some description?  You need to look at the documentation and determine what the proper root-element is

Comment: @ChrisDrappier i am new to the android world can you explain this in the brief ?

Comment: not an android issue. it's an xml thing. read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/